# Kubernetes CronJob to copy, modify and create a secret

Tags: python, bash, kubernetes

I am currently trying to debug the following setup in Kubernetes:
With a Cronjob, I want to read a secret from a namespace, delete some labels in the secret and then create the new secret in another namespace. For some reason, the following code (see CronJob) does not do what it's supposed to and I can't figure out why, strangely, I do not see the pod being created. Before, during debugging the roles, I could always see the pods in CrashLoopBackOff, now I do not even see the pod being created.

Executing the exact commands that you can see in the CronJob manually works perfectly well, the secret gets copied, modified and then the new secret gets created.

These are my Roles:

```
kind: Role
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
metadata:
  namespace: monitoring
  name: secrets-editor
rules:
  - apiGroups: [""]
    resources:
      - secrets
    verbs:
      - 'patch'
      - 'get'
      - 'create'

---
kind: Role
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
metadata:
  namespace: testns
  name: secrets-editor
rules:
  - apiGroups:  [""]
    resources:
      - secrets
    verbs:
      - 'patch'
      - 'get'
      - 'create'
```

These are my Rolebindings:

```
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
kind: RoleBinding
metadata:
  creationTimestamp: null
  name: cronjob-runner-binding
  namespace: testns
roleRef:
  apiGroup: ""
  kind: Role
  name: secrets-editor
subjects:
  - kind: ServiceAccount
    name: sa-cronjob-runner
    namespace: testns

---
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
kind: RoleBinding
metadata:
  creationTimestamp: null
  name: cronjob-runner-binding
  namespace: monitoring
roleRef:
  apiGroup: ""
  kind: Role
  name: secrets-editor
subjects:
  - kind: ServiceAccount
    name: sa-cronjob-runner
    namespace: monitoring
```

ServiceAccount:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: ServiceAccount
metadata:
  name: sa-cronjob-runner
  namespace: testns

---
apiVersion: v1
kind: ServiceAccount
metadata:
  name: sa-cronjob-runner
  namespace: monitoring
```

delete_unneeded_entries.py

```
import yaml

new_namespace = "monitoring"
labels_not_to_delete = ["app.kubernetes.io/instance"]

with open('secret.yaml', 'r') as file:
    secret_yaml = yaml.safe_load(file)

for k, v in list(secret_yaml["metadata"]["labels"].items()):
    if k not in labels_not_to_delete:
        del secret_yaml["metadata"]["labels"][k]

try:
    del secret_yaml["metadata"]["ownerReferences"]
except KeyError:
    print('Key ownerReferences does not exist. Continue.')

secret_yaml["metadata"]["namespace"] = new_namespace

with open('new_secret.yaml', 'w') as file:
    yaml.safe_dump(secret_yaml, file)
```

CronJob:

```
apiVersion: batch/v1
kind: CronJob
metadata:
  name: my-cronjob
spec:
  schedule: "*/1 * * * *"
  jobTemplate:
    spec:
      template:
        spec:
          serviceAccountName: sa-cronjob-runner
          containers:
            - name: hello
              image: haraldott/harri-test1:latest
              command:
                - /bin/sh
                - "-c"
                - |
                  /bin/bash <<'EOF'

                  kubectl get secret mysecret -n testns -oyaml > secret.yaml
                  python3 delete_unneeded_entries.py
                  kubectl apply -f new_secret.yaml

                  EOF
          restartPolicy: OnFailure
```

Dockerfile to have a bitnami/kubectl image and also python

```
FROM bitnami/kubectl:latest as kubectl
FROM ubuntu:latest

# Install Python and any necessary dependencies
RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get install -y python3 python3-pip
RUN pip3 install pyyaml

COPY --from=kubectl /opt/bitnami/kubectl/bin/kubectl /usr/local/bin/
COPY delete_unneeded_entries.py /app/delete_unneeded_entries.py

# Set the working directory
WORKDIR /app
```

The secret looks something like this:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Secret
metadata:
  creationTimestamp: "2023-09-26T12:02:36Z"
  labels:
    app.kubernetes.io/instance: testinstance
    app.kubernetes.io/managed-by: test1
    app.kubernetes.io/name: test2
    app.kubernetes.io/part-of: test3
  name: mysecret
  namespace: testns
  resourceVersion: "4702"
  uid: 7f5f3c3e-5c73-11ee-8c99-0242ac120002
type: Opaque
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out by checking with

```
kubectl get events

Error creating: pods "my-cronjob-28263295-" is forbidden: error looking up service account default/sa-cronjob-runner: serviceaccount "sa-cronjob-runner" not found
```

Solution:
You only need one ServiceAccount in the default namespace:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: ServiceAccount
metadata:
  name: sa-cronjob-runner
  namespace: default
```

Rolebindings have to be adapted accordingly:

replace the namespace under `subjects.namespace` for both Rolebindings with `default` (i.e. the namespace of the correct ServiceAccount).

Hope this might help someone in the future.